# How to out JSON to japanese rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Currenly, I want to JSON format to Japanese. But JSON out don't to Japanese.

JSON Out:

```
{
 status: 200,
 messages: "OK",
 results: [
  {
   id: 3,
   code: "just_item",
   name: "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®"
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   code: "all_item",
   name: "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®"
  }
 ]
}
```

But I want to JSON like:

```
{
 status: 200,
 messages: "OK",
 results: [
  {
   id: 3,
   code: "just_item",
   name: "全商品"
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   code: "all_item",
   name: "全商品"
  }
 ]
}
```

How to JSON format form "åäºŒæ¡è¥¿ä¸€ä¸ç›®" to "全商品" like [URL](http://geoapi.heartrails.com/api/json?method=searchByPostal&postal=0010012)

Comment: Which code are you using to format first example? Which Ruby version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an issue with character-encoding.

Depending on where you get the content of your json from, you might need to `force_encoding` or `encode` to the proper charset.

doing this depends very much on your ruby version and the default character-encoding of your operating system or rails app or whatever you use to output that string.

```
response = {
 status: 200,
 messages: "OK",
 results: [
  {
   id: 3,
   code: "just_item",
   name: "全商品"
  },
  {
   id: 4,
   code: "all_item",
   name: "全商品"
  }
 ]
}
puts response
```

result with ruby 2.2.0p0 (2014-12-25 revision 49005) [x86_64-darwin14]

```
{:status=>200, :messages=>"OK", :results=>[{:id=>3, :code=>"just_item", :name=>"全商品"}, {:id=>4, :code=>"all_item", :name=>"全商品"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks you,but I want to object to utf-8. Because a object have japanese so much.